# When I log in to my router admin page, it doesn't load

Tags: windows-10, router, browser, ip, login

Using a Netgear router (R6100) and when I log in with the default username and password, the login appears to be accepted but the page never loads....

I have used both log-in sites — a Netgear can log in using default gateway (checked via ipconfig) and also at "www.routerlogin.net".

I have used multiple browsers. Google Chrome appears to load continuously after login in and Microsoft Edge says it has loaded but displays a blank screen.

I am not currently using any proxies or a VPN server.

I am hardwired via ethernet, and my internet works fine. I have completely unplugged my wireless antenna as well to make sure my connection is wired. The ethernet slot on my router has a green light beside it, indicating the connection is fine.

I have tried power cycling the router. This did not change anything.

I have tried clearing browser caches. This also changed nothing.

What I have not done thus far: I have not done any work with driver reinstallation for any components. I had device manager do its usual "check for updates" feature but that's it. I also have not factory reset my router; there are settings on it that I would rather not replace.

Is there some quirk to Netgear routers that I am missing? They often don't behave like most do. Otherwise, what further actions can I take before I have to resort to resetting my router and all of its settings?

Comment: I use IE and firefox when chrome gives me issues. I have a couple cisco devices that only seem to play well with Microsoft IE in compatibility view/mode. But this isn't normal behavior for Netgear. They are usually pretty straight forward.

Comment: Also, make sure you login using the ipaddress of the router, not its dns.